# Unable to fetch successful Adapter response before logging in to Application when tested on Android Emulator/Device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am unable to invoke the Adapter response successfully before login when using an Android device/emulator. I am using Adapter based Authentication mechanism to Authenticate with the application.

Further using `securityTest="wl_unprotected"` for the adapter procedure which needs the protection.

Also I am using the `mobileSecurityTest` as shown in the below "authenticationConfig.xml" and **application-descriptor.xml** files below.

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<securityTests> 
    <mobileSecurityTest name="MS1"> 
       <testUser realm="AuthRealm"/>
       <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
</securityTests>

<realms>    
<realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="AuthRealm">
    <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
    <parameter name="login-function" value="PushAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
    <parameter name="logout-function" value="PushAdapter.onLogout"/>
</realm>
</realms>       

<loginModules>
   <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="AuthLoginModule">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
    </loginModules>
</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

application-descriptor.xml

```
<android securityTest="MS1" version="1.0">
  <worklightSettings include="false"/>
  <pushSender key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" senderId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  <security>
    <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
    <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    <publicSigningKey/>
    <packageName/>
  </security>
```

Adapter Implementation

**AdapterAuth.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wl:adapter name="PushAdapter" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>PushAdapter</displayName>
    <description>PushAdapter</description>

    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
                <protocol>http</protocol>
                <domain>xxxx</domain>
                 <port>xxxx</port>           
                <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>100000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
                <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>50000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
                <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>20</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="submitAuthentication" securityTest="wl_unprotected" />

</wl:adapter>
```

**AdapterAuth-impl.js**

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    return 
    {
        authRequired: true,       
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthentication(user, password)
{
    if (username === "user" && password === "user")
    {

        userIdentity = 
        {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username, 
                attributes: {}
        };

        return 
        {
            authRequired: false     
        };  
    }

    else
    {       
        return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
    }
}

function onLogout()
{
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", null);
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

I have implemented the challenge handler functionality in the Angularjs controller and able successfully login with the credentials.

The issue which I am facing is when I try to invoke an adapter procedure before Authentication. The application works fine when tested on browser/Simulator. But I face the issue when I test the same on Android emulator/device.

Consider the below scenario where I have got a button below the login form which fetches the response from the Adapter procedure "getResponse" as shown in the below adapter.

demoAdapter

**demoAdapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<wl:adapter name="demoAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>demoAdapter</displayName>
    <description>demoAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>xxxxxx</domain>
            <port>xx</port> 
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getResponse"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

**demoAdapter-impl.js**

```
function getResponse() 
{

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Android Logcat

```
D/WLNativeXHR(1202): callback {"headers":{"Date":"Thu, 05 Nov 2015 08:26:14 GMT","Content-Length":"74","P3P":"policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"","Expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Pragma":"no-cache","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},"status":200,"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"errorMessage\":null,\"isSuccessful\":true,\"authRequired\":true}*/","statusText":"OK"}
```

The above log is the one which I see when I am trying to invoke the adapter procedure tested on Android Emulator.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: This really doesn't look like [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are prompted for authentication when you invoke the adapter in Android is because your are protecting your Android application with a security test.

```
<android securityTest="MS1" version="1.0">
```

For more information about application authenticity visit https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html?lang=en